# How To fetch last id from database in laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to fetch value from database to my web page.
My database table **WysTeachermessage**

```
id sendname  replyname     message    stop_id    start_id

1   x           y            hai           2          1

2   y           x            hai           2          1
```

I want only last message from this table

```
id sendname    replyname   message    stop_id    start_id

2   y              x          hai           2          1
```

I am using controller code

```
$send_stop=['sendname'=>x,'replyname'=>y,'stop_id'=>2,'start_stop'=>1];
      $receiver_stop=['replyname'=>x,'sendname'=>y,'stop_id'=>2,'start_id'=>1];
      $teacherinboxes=WysTeachermessage::where($send_stop)
                                        ->orWhere($receiver_stop)
                                        ->orWhere('stop_id',0)
                                        ->orderBy('id','desc')
                                        ->get();
```

How to fetch last id values from database.??

my controller code

`$adm_msg=array();
        foreach($students as $student)
        {
          $send_stop=['student_id'=>$student->id,'receiver_id'=>$userid];
          $receiver_stop=['student_id'=>$student->id,'sender_id'=>$userid];
          $parent_messages=WysMessage::where($send_stop)
                                        ->orWhere($receiver_stop)
                                         ->orderBy('id','desc')
                                        ->first();
            $adm_msg[$student->id] = $parent_messages['send_msg'];
         }
         $students=WysStudent::all(); 
         $parent =WysParent::all();
         $clss = DB::table('wys_classes')
              ->join('wys_classnames', 'wys_classes.cls', '=', 'wys_classnames.id')
              ->join('wys_divnames', 'wys_classes.divn', '=', 'wys_divnames.id')
              ->select('wys_classes.id', 'wys_classnames.classname', 'wys_divnames.divname')
              ->get();
          $send_stop=['receiver_id'=>$userid,'parent_stop_id'=>1,'teacher_stop_id'=>0];
          $receiver_stop=['sender_id'=>$userid,'parent_stop_id'=>0,'teacher_stop_id'=>0];
          $recv_stop=['receiver_id'=>$userid,'parent_stop_id'=>0,'teacher_stop_id'=>0];
          $send_admin=['sender_id'=>$userid,'parent_stop_id'=>1,'teacher_stop_id'=>0];
          $parent_messages=WysMessage::where($send_stop)
                                      ->orWhere($receiver_stop)
                                      ->orWhere($send_admin)
                                      ->orWhere($recv_stop)
                                      ->orderBy('id','desc')
                                      ->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Just use first() instead of get()

```
$teacherinboxes=WysTeachermessage::where($send_stop)
                                    ->orWhere($receiver_stop)
                                    ->orWhere('stop_id',0)
                                    ->orderBy('id','desc') 
                                    ->first(); // use first() instead of get()
```

Comment: i also thought code but its not work .. because sendname(x) send msg to another one(z) that stop_id=0 if using this code not work.

Comment: in $send_stop, you wrote 'start_stop' there, is this a typo? or should this be 'start_id' instead? could you provide more explanation to what is stop_id and start_id?

Comment: sir ,  full controller code is above...iam asking to you an example of my code. .parent_stop_id and teacher_stop_id as stop_id ans start_id.  i want   $send_stop and  $send_admin check ,then its true only display last value similar to above table.